# semi perfect number - number of divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

The definition:
we define number as semi perfect , if the number equals to the sum of exactly k of its divisors.

the question:
prove that for every n (n>0 | n belong to N)
n is semi perfect order 3 if and only if n is divided by 6.

my attempt:

<-

n is divided by 6
because of that, its divisors are $$\frac{n}{6} ,\frac{n}{2} ,\frac{n}{3} $$

we will sum those 3 divisors - $$\frac{n}{6} + \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{3} = n$$
and we finished the proof for one side

->

this is the side I have a bit more problem with
I know n uphold the definition above
but Im having trouble proving that n is divided by 6 with no remainder.

I thought maybe trying with contradiction ( assuming it doesnt divided by 6)
but still stuck with this question

would love to please have some help with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof that multiples of 6 work already contains a good hint for the other direction: It uses the fact that
$$ \frac12+\frac13+\frac16=1.$$
Perhaps try to find (or rather: show that one cannot find) any other integer triple $(a,b,c)$ with $1<a<b<c$ and
$$ \frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=1.$$

> From $$1=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c<\frac1a+\frac1a+\frac1a,$$ we obtain $a<3$, i.e., necessarily $a=2$. After this, from $$ \frac12=1-\frac1a=\frac1b+\frac1c<\frac1b+\frac1b, $$ we obtain $b<4$, so necessarily $b=3$. Finally, $\frac1c=1-\frac12-\frac13$ implies $c=6$.